# Expand the control

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8.1, windows-10, uwp

I've got a custom set of controls:

```
 <Border Height="55" Margin="5,14,5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock x:Name="SubjectNo" Text="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="36" Margin="0,1,36,0" d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="Subject" Text="Subject NAME more " TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="26,0,90,19" d:LayoutOverrides="Height, TopPosition, BottomPosition" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="Teacher" Text="BIG NAME HERE" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="14.667" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="26,0,0,9" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="106" Height="17" d:LayoutOverrides="VerticalAlignment" />
            <Grid Height="15" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="133,0,0,10" d:LayoutOverrides="VerticalAlignment">
                <TextBlock x:Name="BegTime" Text="12:55 AM" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="13.333" d:LayoutOverrides="Height, TopPosition, BottomPosition" SelectionHighlightColor="White" Margin="8,0,-8,0" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="EndTime" Text="12:55 PM" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="13.333" Margin="68,0,-12,0" d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment, Height, TopPosition, BottomPosition" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="Line" Text="-" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="13.333" Margin="64,0,0,0" d:LayoutOverrides="Height, TopPosition, BottomPosition" />
            </Grid>
            <Border Margin="281,4,10,6" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" d:LayoutOverrides="TopPosition, BottomPosition" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="57">
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="RoomNo" Text="1255" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="24" d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment, Width, TopPosition, BottomPosition" Margin="2,10,-2,0" />
                    <TextBlock x:Name="RoomWritten" Text="Room" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="14.667" VerticalAlignment="Top"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment, Width" Margin="9,0,4,0"/>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <AppBarButton x:Name="appBarButton" Label="" Margin="158,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="32" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Icon="Remote" Height="13" d:LayoutOverrides="VerticalAlignment"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
```

[It looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGGZv.png)

Now I want to add a button like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yErhr.png) to make my control show additional info in the bottom, so I want it to expand from the bottom and show additional textblock, like windows 10 notification center does. Than the icon changes and when I press the button again, additional info hides. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Take a look at the [Expander Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.expander(v=vs.110).aspx) - you could place the always visible content in the header, and add the additional content as the content.

Answer (score 0):

The type of control you are looking for is called a `ToggleButton`. It has an `IsChecked` state property to facilitate the two states for your "open" and "closed". The logic and styling for what is displayed by you when `IsChecked` is `true` or `false` can be controlled via styles.

More information on [MSDN: ToggleButton class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.togglebutton)

Comment: I think it's not what I want. For example, in windows notification area, you can make the message short or show it all using the expand button. I want to do the same